# Automatic Touch Screen

Tags: android, eclipse, touch

Is there a way I can simulate a touch of the screen in my app? To touch automatically a specific point of the screen for example as soon as my app starts. Thanks a lot

Comment: No, not from within your app. And it wouldn't be necessary anyway, as you can just do programmatically whatever your app would do when that point on the screen is touched. I suspect you want to tap outside of your app, maybe to invoke a system function or change a setting -- and that is, for quite obvious reasons, verboten. If you want to simulate screen taps for testing purposes, you can use monkeyrunner over usb.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clearing to understanding of your question. May be you want to like this when your screen start then input giving window come at a time.If you wants this. then try like code in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".TodoEdit"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

here TodoEdit your activity package name and acivity name. For example

```
"com.example.cg.TodoEdit"
```

For more info you can follow [Android windowSoftInputMode – Resize the application for the soft-keyboard](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/)